# WooCommerce: Site-wide cookie filter

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We need set site-wide cookie filter by brands.

WooComerce have build-in Brands taxonomy.

At the start landing page user will be select one from several brands. And after, user views products on site only by selected brand. If user will visit brand url (*www.example.com/brands/brand-second*), then need change filter to another brand, and shows products only by last selected brand. Others products not allowed to shows (another brand or without brand).

What any ideas for realize this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try hold the visible brand in a cookie, and use `woocommerce_product_query` or `pre_get_posts` filters to filter according to that cookie value.

Each time the user visits that brand URL, change the cookie value.

Comment: For example, How may override query to filter products by brand with `woocommerce_product_query`?

Answer (score -1):

I found solution for my question!

```
function filter_products_by_brand( $q ) {

    $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'brand',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'dobro' ),  // Don't display products in the clothing category on the shop page.
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );

    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_products_by_brand' );
```